# Are regular VACUUM ANALYZE still recommended under 9.1?

Tags: postgresql, etl, vacuum

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1 on Ubuntu. Are scheduled `VACUUM ANALYZE` still recommended, or is autovacuum enough to take care of all needs?

If the answer is "it depends", then:

- I have a largish database (30 GiB compressed dump size, 200 GiB data directory)
- I do ETL into the database, importing close to 3 million rows per week
- The tables with the most frequent changes are all inherited from a master table, with no data in the master table (data is partitioned by week)
- I create hourly rollups, and from there, daily, weekly and monthly reports

I'm asking because the scheduled `VACUUM ANALYZE` is impacting my reporting. It runs for more than 5 hours, and I've had to kill it twice this week, because it was impacting regular database imports. `check_postgres` doesn't report any significant bloat on the database, so that's not really an issue.

From the docs, autovacuum should take care of transaction ID wrap around as well. The question stands: do I still need a `VACUUM ANALYZE`?

Comment: Well, I would say 'no', but elaborating this answer (setting the autovacuum parameters for example) would need some experiments on a replica DB.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

VACUUM is only needed on updated or deleted rows in non-temporary tables. Obviously you're doing lots of INSERTs but it's not obvious from the description that you're also doing lots of UPDATEs or DELETEs.

These operations can be tracked with the `pg_stat_all_tables` view, specifically the `n_tup_upd` and `n_tup_del` columns. Also, even more to the point, there is a `n_dead_tup` column that tells, per table, how much rows need to be vacuumed.
(see [Monitoring statistics](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/monitoring-stats.html) in the doc for functions and views related to statistics gathering).

A possible strategy in your case would be to suppress the scheduled VACUUM, keeping an eye on this view and checking on which tables the `n_dead_tup` is going up significantly. Then apply the aggressive VACUUM to these tables only. This will be a win if there are large tables whose rows never get deleted nor updated and the aggressive VACUUM is really necessary only on smaller tables.

But keep running the ANALYZE for the optimizer to always have fresh statistics.

Comment: Autovacuum also takes care of ANALYZE. It is still a good idea to run a manual ANALYZE between a bulk UPDATE / INSERT / DELETE and immediately following big queries. +1 for the good advice, though.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to n_dead_tup and friends. I do have rollup tables on which I frequently (hourly) destroy and recreate thousands of rows. I'll check the values and schedule appropriately.  The answer is always "monitor, think, act" anyway :)

Answer (score 27):

I see nothing in your question that `autovacuum` would not take care of. It largely depends on the **pattern of your writing activities**. You mention 3 million *new* rows per week, but `INSERT` (or `COPY`) typically don't create table and index bloat. (`autovacuum` only has to take care of [column statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-stats.html), the [visibility map](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-vm.html) and some minor jobs). `UPDATE` and `DELETE` are the dominant cause of table and index bloat, especially when targeting random rows. I don't see any of that in your question.

`autovacuum` has come a long way and is doing a great job in Postgres 9.1 or later. I would have a look at the [`autovacuum` settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html). If vacuuming tends to interfere with your work load, also have a look at ["Cost-based Vacuum Delay"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-VACUUM-COST). Manual vacuuming should be the rare exception.

If you have lots of random `UPDATE`s, you may want to set the [`FILLFACTOR`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-STORAGE-PARAMETERS) to something lower than 100, to allow HOT updates right away and reduce the need for `VACUUM`. More on HOT updates:

- [Redundant data in update statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7806610/939860)

Note also, that **temporary tables** need manual `VACUUM` & `ANALYZE`. I quote [the manual on `CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):

> The [autovacuum daemon](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM) cannot access and therefore cannot vacuum or
>   analyze temporary tables. For this reason, appropriate vacuum and
>   analyze operations should be performed via session SQL commands. For
>   example, if a temporary table is going to be used in complex queries,
>   it is wise to run `ANALYZE` on the temporary table after it is populated.

Answer (score 7):

While I agree that using the auto features is best instead of running it database wide, in most cases per table tuning is necessary.

I don't quite agree with the design choice of postgres to tie together vacuum and analyze, I have seen several instances where databases that do a lot of insert/update but little delete never get analyze done and start to perform badly.

The solution is to go into the tables that get used heavily and are subject to large queries and set the auto analyze settings for those tables down to something to where they are getting analyzed once or every other day.

You can get to the per table settings in the gui on the auto vacuum tab and you will see analyze settings there which you can set independently of vacuum.

The settings end up in the reloptions table and can be seen with the query

```
SELECT c.relname, c.reloptions FROM pg_class c where reloptions is not null
```

and a sample value there of an agressive analyze might be

```
{autovacuum_enabled=true,autovacuum_analyze_threshold=10,autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor=.01}
```

To see when the last time your tables got auto analyzed query

```
select 
    relname, 
    n_dead_tup, 
    n_tup_ins, 
    n_tup_upd, 
    n_tup_del, 
    last_autoanalyze, 
    autoanalyze_count 
from pg_stat_user_tables 
where last_autoanalyze is not null 
order by last_autoanalyze desc;
```

Comment: If you don't `ANALYZE`, how PostgreSQL will know that the stats changed?  And how can you determine that it is `ANALYZE` which takes a long time?  At the same time, while it is not quite clear which GUI you mention above, you are right in that specific per-table settings may be useful.