# How to make this query use my multicolumn index?

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, postgresql-performance

Currently, I have a view which is defined like this:

```
                       View "public.customer_list"
  Column   |          Type           | Modifiers | Storage  | Description 
-----------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------
 id        | bigint                  |           | plain    | 
 name      | character varying(100)  |           | extended | 
 street    | character varying(100)  |           | extended | 
 zip       | character varying(10)   |           | extended | 
 city      | character varying(100)  |           | extended | 
 country   | character varying(3)    |           | extended | 
 phone     | character varying(100)  |           | extended | 
 mail      | character varying(100)  |           | extended | 
 rating    | integer                 |           | plain    | 
 salesnote | character varying(1800) |           | extended | 
View definition:
 SELECT c.id,
    c.name,
    a.street,
    a.zip,
    a.city,
    a.country,
    c.phone,
    c.mail,
    c.rating,
    c.salesnote
   FROM crm_customer c
     JOIN crm_address a ON a.id = c.address_id;
```

To better search through the List I created an index with the following:

```
CREATE INDEX crm_customer_big_index 
    ON crm_customer (name ASC, 
                     name text_pattern_ops, 
                     (id::text) text_pattern_ops, 
                     phone text_pattern_ops, 
                     mail text_pattern_ops, 
                     rating);
```

I search through this table with a varying where query mostly it looks like that:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM customer_list
 WHERE lower(name::text) LIKE 'env%' 
       AND rating = 3 
 ORDER BY name ASC 
 LIMIT 20 
 OFFSET 0;
```

But still my analyzer won't ever use an index. Is there a way to use one?

```
             QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=164.04..164.08 rows=15 width=129) (actual time=3.243..3.244 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=164.04..164.08 rows=15 width=129) (actual time=3.243..3.243 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: c.name
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..163.75 rows=15 width=129) (actual time=0.020..3.225 rows=1 loops=1)
               ->  Seq Scan on crm_customer c  (cost=0.00..111.13 rows=15 width=98) (actual time=0.012..3.216 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((rating = 3) AND (lower((name)::text) ~~ 'env%'::text))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 2978
               ->  Index Only Scan using crm_address_search_index on crm_address a  (cost=0.28..3.50 rows=1 width=47) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (id = c.address_id)
                     Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning time: 0.580 ms
 Execution time: 3.286 ms
```

Currently, the query is still "somewhat" fast. However, I could have way more data inside my table. Also, `crm_address` has an index over `street, zip, city, country`, which works fine.

Comment: I'm no expert on postgresql, but I believe that the function ( lower ) in your predicate will make uit difficult to use the index. Have you tried to create an index with an expression? I.e. `CREATE INDEX ... ON ...(lower(name), ...)`

Comment: eh yes I alread did that, and had the same behavior..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression `lower(name::text)` is not covered by your index, which also does not seem to be useful *at all*, at least for what we see in your question:

```
CREATE INDEX crm_customer_big_index 
    ON crm_customer (name ASC, 
                     name text_pattern_ops, 
                     (id::text) text_pattern_ops, 
                     phone text_pattern_ops, 
                     mail text_pattern_ops, 
                     rating);
```

This index would cover your query:

```
CREATE INDEX crm_customer_foo_index ON crm_customer (
  rating
, lower(name::text) text_pattern_ops
, address_id);  -- for the join
```

To optimize, I suggest to adapt your query additionally:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   customer_list
WHERE  lower(name::text) LIKE 'env%' 
AND    rating = 3 
ORDER  BY lower(name::text), name
LIMIT  20;
```

Also, ***if*** you are only interested in the first few characters of `name character varying(100)`, make the index shorter and faster by just indexing those first few characters:

```
CREATE INDEX crm_customer_foo_index ON crm_customer (
     rating
   , lower(left(name::text, 7)) text_pattern_ops  -- example with local optimum
   , address_id);  -- for the join
```

The query must match the index expression:

```
WHERE  lower(left(name::text, 7)) LIKE 'env%' 
...
ORDER  BY lower(left(name::text, 7)), name
```

Not sure if the view is in the way somehow. But it should be transparent.

I wouldn't use `varchar(n)` at all. Just `text`:

- [Should I add an arbitrary length limit to VARCHAR columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20974/should-i-add-an-arbitrary-length-limit-to-varchar-columns/21496#21496)

About pattern matching and `text_pattern_ops`:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions/10696#10696)

Why did I put `rating` first in the index?

- [Multicolumn index and performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33196/multicolumn-index-and-performance/33220#33220)

There are query techniques to better capitalize on non-leading index columns. Consider the [Postgres Wiki on "Loose indexscan"](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan#Making_use_of_a_non-leading_column_of_an_index).

Comment: but that will only works if rating is set, correct? I tried and never get anything else to work, also I can't search for ```lower(mail) LIKE 'mymail@%'``` somehow strange.  However I firstly need to read your links now thanks!

Comment: @ChristianSchmitt: Yes, that index is for when there is an equality predicate on `rating` in your query ([*mostly*](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7484/3684)).

Comment: oh and I know that i doesn't need to use varchar(n), currently crm_customer is a really really old table (created 3 years ago). On newers I avoided varchar at all. I don't have any Data which needs a length restrictions, however some of the data got converted from mysql where you use it. before we used char(n) migrated to varchar(n) and now we've seen that we could use only text. ;) still thanks for the hint.

Comment: @ChristianSchmitt: [`char(n)` would be a mistake. The choice between `varchar(n)`  and `text` is not as clear.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89433/3684) `text` is just my personal preference to keep things simple.

Answer (score 3):

The planner/optimizer will choose using an index if (and only if) the cost estimates suggest that the query would run faster/cheaper.  (There are many simplifications in the previous sentence, but that's the essence.)  This means that the index must support the query - give a faster way of finding the necessary rows, of ordering or other operations.

At the same time, reading the index is basically the same operation as reading a table.  Now if the planner finds that it needs to read the index, then go to the table to fetch the rows, it might decide that this is too expensive and would use a sequential scan instead.

There are factors which point towards *not* using an index.

1. the lack of any suitable ones - in most cases, it means that the first column of any index does not fit any `WHERE` condition or ordering of your query
2. if the order of columns makes it hard to find the necessary rows
3. if an index is too big (contains too many columns

(There are possibly others, too, but in our case these are the important things.)

Let's reiterate your query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM customer_list
 WHERE lower(name::text) LIKE 'env%' 
       AND rating = 3 
 ORDER BY name ASC
 LIMIT 20 
 OFFSET 0;
```

Which is, effectively, would be translated into the following:

```
SELECT c.id,
       c.name,
       a.street,
       a.zip,
       a.city,
       a.country,
       c.phone,
       c.mail,
       c.rating,
       c.salesnote
 FROM crm_customer c
 JOIN crm_address a ON a.id = c.address_id
 WHERE lower(name::text) LIKE 'env%' 
       AND rating = 3 
 ORDER BY name ASC
 LIMIT 20 
 OFFSET 0;
```

The `WHERE` clause needs to find the rows partly based on an expression.  Your index lacks this expression.  This is a case 1 in the above list.  Then `rating` is the last column - the given rating is as hard to find in the index as it can be.  Here we stumble upon case 2.  And, overall, your index might be nearly as big as your table (without seeing the table definition, this is just a guess) - it is simply too expensive to use.

If you create the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON crm_customer ((lower(name::text) text_pattern_ops, rating, address_id); -- thanks, Erwin
```

there are chances it would be used.  It helps finding the rows in `crm_customer`, then gives the `address_id` to use in the join.

If you can change your logic slightly and do an

```
ORDER BY lower(name)
```

this ordering would be facilitated by the same index, too - in this case, you'd lose the distinction between values like 'environment' and 'Environment'.

**Notes:**

- I suggest you reading the excellent [Use The Index, Luke](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) pages.  It gives a nice and thorough introduction to using indexes.
- I was not careful enough to include the join in my index definition.  The [excellent answer from Erwin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/116709/6219) made me notice my fault - I've now edited it in, but the source is not mine.

Comment: Wow also thanks, postgresql people are so helpful. It's an awesome database! still somewhat slow for lists but currently this is not that much of a problem if I can hit some indexes!