# Strategies for reducing data to summaries within a table over time?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I have a large data set where large numbers of entries differ only by timestamp.  In the short term it's beneficial to maintain individual entries so that we can correlate by time for individual data points.  But after enough time passes, that level of granularity is unnecessary and I'm comfortable replacing those individual entries with a summarized entry by means of a count column.

So if the table has entries this when it's fresh:

```
+---------------------+------+-------+
| stamp               | data | count |
+---------------------+------+-------+
| 2016/01/01:12:54:00 | abcd | 1     |
| 2016/01/01:12:56:58 | abcd | 1     |
| 2016/01/01:13:02:36 | abcd | 1     |
+---------------------+------+-------+
```

I'm happy to combine all the entries of a given hour after, say, a week:

```
+---------------------+------+-------+
| stamp               | data | count |
+---------------------+------+-------+
| 2016/01/01:12:00:00 | abcd | 2     |
| 2016/01/01:13:00:00 | abcd | 1     |
+---------------------+------+-------+
```

And maybe after a month I only care about the granularity of a day:

```
+---------------------+------+-------+
| stamp               | data | count |
+---------------------+------+-------+
| 2016/01/01:00:00:00 | abcd | 3     |
+---------------------+------+-------+
```

This isn't hard to do in SQL (PostgreSQL shown here):

```
select distinct(date_trunc('hour', stamp),data,sum(count) 
into table tmpdata
from data
where stamp < now() - interval '7 days'
group by date_trunc('hour', stamp),data;
```

...and then clear the rows I just summarized out of `data` and replace them with the summaries I created in `tmpdata`...  It seems preferable to keep the data within a single table rather than have separate tables for different granularity of data.

This all works, but it's awkward, and I'd like to learn a better way if there is one.  So I have two questions:

1. What is the name for this sort of summary-replacement-of-data-over-time?  I would say the data is being coalesced, but COALESCE has a distinct other meaning in SQL.  It would help to know the terminology used to describe this sort of thing so I can tag it and talk about it properly.
2. What strategies / algorithms / methods of achieving this goal would you recommend, with an eye towards elegance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply call it "**`aggregation`**".

As for elegance, you can do this with a single SQL command without another table using a [**data-modifying CTE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

For (only) hourly aggregation of rows that are older than a week:

```
WITH del AS (
   DELETE FROM data d
   WHERE  stamp < now() - interval '7 days'   -- ">" would be wrong
   AND   (date_trunc('hour', stamp) <> stamp  -- not truncated yet.
          OR EXISTS (  -- more than one in same hour
             SELECT 1
             FROM   data
             WHERE  date_trunc('hour', stamp) = date_trunc('hour', d.stamp)
             AND    ctid <> d.ctid   -- except self
             )
         )
   RETURNING *
   )
INSERT INTO data(stamp, data, count) 
SELECT date_trunc('hour', stamp), data, sum(count)
FROM   del
GROUP  BY 1,2;
```

Only replaces rows that *need* replacing. Repeated calls would not repeat writes.

If you *know* a lower bound where all rows have been aggregated already, add another `WHERE` condition to make it faster:

```
AND stamp > $lower_bound
```

Obviously, you need an index on `stamp` or, ideally, a **partial index** only including rows younger than `$lower_bound` that would need to be recreated from time to time. Related:

- [PostgreSQL partial index unused when created on a table with existing data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/99323/postgresql-partial-index-unused-when-created-on-a-table-with-existing-data/99324#99324)
- [Add datetime constraint to a PostgreSQL multi-column partial index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14746476/939860)

Using `ctid` since no PK is defined.

- [In-order sequence generation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17503095/939860)
- [How do I decompose ctid into page and row numbers?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65964/how-do-i-decompose-ctid-into-page-and-row-numbers/66007#66007)

You may want to `VACUUM FULL data;` to reclaim table bloat after that. But be aware of implications. Maybe [`pg_repack`](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack) is for you:

- [VACUUM returning disk space to operating system](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37028/vacuum-returning-disk-space-to-operating-system/37032#37032)

Aside: `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` was redundant in your original query. And you were aggregating rows *younger* than a week instead of *older*.

Comment: Thank you, excellent answer, I appreciate how you've given me several things to learn about PostgreSQL while helping me with the smaller bug.  I did edit my original to replace '>' with '<' to avoid later users getting tripped up on my typo; I left the 'distinct...group from' in as a less typo-ish stupidity that others can learn from when they read your answer.