# How can I order the results from a DISTINCT ON query

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

I have a table with the equivalent of:

```
group_id integer REFERENCES <some other table>
item_id integer REFERECNES <some other table>
timestamp date
data text
sort_order text
```

I want to get the latest `data` for every item before some date. I.e. the maximum `timestamp` less than some value. I also want these rows sorted on `sort_order`.

After som Googling I find that `SELECT DISTINCT ON` is what I want, so I get something like

```
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (item_id)
         data
    FROM [this table]
   WHERE group_id = [some value]
     AND timestamp < [some value]
ORDER BY item_id, timestamp DESC
```

Now, I actually want the data sorted on `sort_order`, but `DISTINCT ON` requires the `ORDER BY` to be listed first.

One solution that comes to mind is to wrap all of this in an outer `SELECT` that will `ORDER BY sort_order`. Is that a good efficient solution, or is there a better "correct" way to do this.

(Or, am I in fact not even close...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping the query in a derived table is the obvious way to solve this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (item_id)
             item_id, data, timestamp, sort_order, ... 
        FROM [this table]
       WHERE group_id = [some value]
         AND timestamp < [some value]
    ORDER BY item_id, timestamp DESC
   ) AS t
ORDER BY sort_order ;
```

If your original query is efficient and doesn't return too many rows, the additional sort will not add much cost to the query.

---

Besides `DISTINCT ON`, there are a few other methods that are often more efficient in this type of "greatest-n-pre-group" queries - but efficiency depends on many parameters, like targeted indexes and distribution of values (how many distinct `item_id` in the table, how many rows per `item_id`), Postgres version, etc.

Most notable method is using `LATERAL` subqueries. See these excellent answers by [Erwin Brandstetter](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3684/erwin-brandstetter):

- [Optimize `GROUP BY` query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)
- [Optimize groupwise maximum query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244026/optimize-groupwise-maximum-query/24377356#24377356)
- [Select first row in each `GROUP BY` group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Query last N related rows per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25957558/query-last-n-related-rows-per-row/25965393#25965393)
- [Optimise a `LATERAL JOIN` query on a big table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143044/optimise-a-lateral-join-query-on-a-big-table/143065#143065)