# How can I improve this query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.3, query-performance

I've been using PostgreSQL for a little over a year. I am continually whacked by queries that have `count`s in them, such as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, listings.id AS listings_id
FROM "listings" LEFT OUTER JOIN houses ON houses.id = listings.house_id  
WHERE "listings"."subscription_id" = 123
  AND (exists (select 'x' FROM apps
               WHERE apps.listing_id = listings.id
                 AND apps.subscription_id = listings.subscription_id LIMIT 1)) 
                 AND "listings"."listing_status" = 'Active'
GROUP BY listings.id
```

How can I write this query in PostgreSQL where it will return in a reasonable amount of time?

My explain plan is the following. I admit I really don't know how to read it very well. But it looks bad:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=2579302.75..2579319.31 rows=1656 width=8)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on listings  (cost=304056.70..2579294.47 rows=1656 width=8)
        Recheck Cond: ((subscription_id = 162) AND (listing_status = 'Active'::citext))
        Filter: (SubPlan 1)
        ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=304056.70..304056.70 rows=3313 width=0)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on listings_subscription_item_idx  (cost=0.00..570.84 rows=5637 width=0)
                    Index Cond: (subscription_id = 162)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_listings_on_listing_status  (cost=0.00..303484.78 rows=3936030 width=0)
                    Index Cond: (listing_status = 'Active'::citext)
        SubPlan 1
          ->  Limit  (cost=0.57..683.01 rows=1 width=0)
                ->  Index Scan using apps_listing_idx on apps  (cost=0.57..42312.00 rows=62 width=0)
                      Index Cond: (listing_id = listings.id)
                      Filter: (subscription_id = listings.subscription_id)
```

This query works fantastically on a laptop with the same database, but dies in production and takes over a minute to return. Does anything jump out at anybody for things I could rapidly improve?

The database has `autovacuum` turned on.

Comment: `EXPLAIN (BUFFERS, ANALYZE)` please, the raw `explain` doesn't have timing info etc.

Comment: `I know there is a vacuum done on the database every night.` Why is that? When using autovacuum (as is the default), you typically don't need manual vacuuming. Also: autovacuum also takes care of `ANALYZE`, which you may be missing in this case? Related: [Are regular VACUUM ANALYZE still recommended under 9.1?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18664/3684)

Comment: For somebody requesting answers you are remarkably impervious to requests for clarification yourself. You know the [edit](http://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/106281/edit) button right under your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I immediately see a few things that confuse me here, which you should look into.

## Unnecessary Join

In your query you have a portion

```
...  LEFT OUTER JOIN houses ON houses.id = listings.house_id ...
```

yet no values from the `houses` table are in your `SELECT`.  The good news is that this is not affecting your performance, because the query optimizer has wisely left the `houses` table out of the query entirely.  This does concern me a bit just in principle.

## Odd Query Plan

In your query plan, it chooses to enforce the conditions of

```
subscription_id = ### AND listing_status = 'Active'
```

by performing two `Bitmap Index Scan`s, followed by a subsequent `BitmapAnd`.  This seems like a highly inefficient way to perform this operation when the `Bitmap Index Scan on listings_subscription_item_idx` returns approximately 5637 rows, but the `Bitmap Index Scan on index_listings_on_listing_status` returns over 3 million!

Is there any chance that you have a very large number of entries in `listings` for which `listing_status` is *not* `'Active'`?

In this case, I would think the optimal plan would be to use the `Bitmap Index Scan on listings_subscription_item_idx` to extract a set of candidate rows, and then simply filter this small set of results for `listing_status = 'Active'`.  I'm surprised the optimizer has chosen this plan, but I have a wild guess that it's because the `listing_status = 'Active'` is actually highly selective on that column (such that maybe only 10% or less of the listings are Active).

To try and address this, I suggest trying the following query:

```
WITH listing_by_subscription AS(
SELECT * FROM "listings" 
WHERE "listings"."subscription_id" = 123)
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, listing_by_subscription.id AS listings_id 
FROM listing_by_subscription
WHERE listing_by_subscription."listing_status" = 'Active'
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM apps
            WHERE apps.listing_id = listing_by_subscription.id
            AND apps.subscription_id = listing_by_subscription.subscription_id LIMIT 1)
GROUP BY listing_by_subscription.id;
```

## Optimization Barrier in CTE

Here, I've tried to make use of the optimization barrier found when using a [Common Table Expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html).  Any time you use the `WITH()` expression, the Postgres optimizer treats it as a separate block which it must calculate separately from the overall optimization, sort of like a 'forced materialization'.  In this case, I try to use that to force the most selective predicate, the `subscription_id = ###` portion, to whittle down the result set first.

Try out this query and see if it helps!

## work_mem

Last but not least, there's been a lot of talk abou `work_mem` settings today.  As @CraigRinger mentioned, we really need to see an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS)` to get the complete picture, but I'm wondering if this setting is sufficient.

Check you `postgresql.conf` file, and report back your `work_mem` setting, along with that `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS)`, if you're still having trouble.

Hope this works!

Comment: Chris, I really appreciate your help, a lot. We are basically dead as these queries are now taking over 10K seconds and have brought ops to a halt. Here are those settings: ```work_mem = 64MB``` and 
```maintenance_work_mem = 256MB```

Comment: **1)** Did you try the query I listed above? **2)** Also, can you post the result of an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS)` in an edit to your original post? **3)** Give the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS)` for both your original query, and the suggested query I listed above. **4)** Increase your `work_mem` significantly, and see how the query does.  In some cases, increasing `work_mem` is a "quick fix" which can be used until the actual problem is resolved.

Comment: I did both. I discovered that just deleting that ```listing_status``` index sped things up an order of magnitude. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Another option which may speed up things a bit more would be to build a partial index on the `listing_status` for the condition where it is `Active`, as `CREATE INDEX idx_listings_stats_active ON listings (listing_status) WHERE listing_status = 'Active';`

Comment: I'll keep that in mind: I hadn't considered a partial index. I don't really know what that is, although it seems familiar from my Oracle days years ago.