# Slow query caused by nested loop on simple join?

Tags: postgresql, join, amazon-rds, performance, postgresql-performance

I've been struggling with the performance on a query.  Trying to do a lookup of a large set of ids in a large table (500GB). I create a temporary table of the ids with the ids as a primary key and run analyze after. It takes about 17 seconds to execute the below query for 1000 ids for uncached data (2 seconds cached).  Our typical query is usually for about 100,000 ids which can take 5-12 minutes.  These times are only for the below query and do not include the temp table creation.  Looking at the query plan, its the nested loop that seems to be bogging it down.  We are on the largest RDS machine at 244GB RAM so we can't load the whole table into memory.  What can I do to improve it?

The query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM temp_table 
JOIN large_table ON temp_table.id = large_table.id
```

The output from explain:

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                              QUERY PLAN                                              │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..5420956.52 rows=2682643 width=46)                                           │
│   ->  Seq Scan on temp_table  (cost=0.00..1065.09 rows=73809 width=8) │
│   ->  Index Scan using id_idx on large_table  (cost=0.00..73.07 rows=36 width=46)        │
│         Index Cond: (id = (temp_table.id)::numeric)         │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Running postgresql 9.5.4 on AWS RDS.

## EXTRA INFO

The large_table id field is

```
id │ numeric(18,0)    │ not null
```

While the temp_table id field is

```
id | bigint           | not null default nextval('temp_table_id_seq'::regclass)
```

The indices for the large table:

```
"large_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id, month)
"id_idx" btree (id)
```

Output from EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS):

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                      │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..5420956.52 rows=2682643 width=46) (actual time=0.107..90871.252 rows=745842 loops=1)                                       │
│   Buffers: shared hit=747255 read=163891                                                                                                            │
│   ->  Seq Scan on temp_table  (cost=0.00..1065.09 rows=73809 width=8) (actual time=0.026..29.963 rows=73809 loops=1) │
│         Buffers: shared hit=327                                                                                                                     │
│   ->  Index Scan using id_idx on large_table  (cost=0.00..73.07 rows=36 width=46) (actual time=0.139..1.204 rows=10 loops=73809)        │
│         Index Cond: (id = (temp_table.id)::numeric)                                                        │
│         Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 0                                                                                                            │
│         Buffers: shared hit=746928 read=163891                                                                                                      │
│ Planning time: 0.844 ms                                                                                                                             │
│ Execution time: 91051.477 ms                                                                                                                        │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(10 rows)

Time: 91067.663 ms
```

DB parameters:

```
┌──────────┐
│ work_mem │
├──────────┤
│ 1GB      │
└──────────┘
──────────────────────┐
│ effective_cache_size │
├──────────────────────┤
│ 188781552kB          │
└──────────────────────┘
┌──────────────────┐
│ random_page_cost │
├──────────────────┤
│ 2                │
└──────────────────┘
┌────────────────┐
│ shared_buffers │
├────────────────┤
│ 62927184kB     │
└────────────────┘
```

## UPDATE 1

Tried to do a `SELECT cols FROM large_table WHERE id = ANY (VALUES (1), (2),....)` which yielded a `HashAggregate` instead of a `SeqScan` but it took almost 8 minutes for 21,000 ids.

```
Nested Loop  (cost=321.26..15436.17 rows=275581120 width=38)
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=320.69..322.69 rows=200 width=8)
        Group Key: ("*VALUES*".column1)::numeric
        ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..267.24 rows=21379 width=8)
  ->  Index Scan using id_idx on large_table  (cost=0.58..75.21 rows=36 width=46)
        Index Cond: (id = ("*VALUES*".column1)::numeric)
```

Comment: Be aware that temp tables need manual analyze (and vacuum): http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18664/are-regular-vacuum-analyze-still-recommended-under-9-1/18694#18694

Comment: Is the `large_table . id` numeric(18,8) as well? Can you add the `CREATE TABLE` for both tables?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I cleared up id types for both tables.  Can't really add the CREATE TABLE for the large one as its 232 columns.

Comment: The issue is right there then. You are **joining columns with different types**. Why is the temp_table `id` numeric and not bigint as the other table?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ tried the same type for the temp table, still slow.

Comment: Shouldn't it just lookup the id in large_table's index and return all the matching rows?  Why is it doing this cartesian join?