# Function which returns a table for a selected period of time

Tags: postgresql, performance, execution-plan, plpgsql

I have a PostgreSQL function on my hands.

The function works but the results are very slow. I'm hopping someone will be able to help me reduce the execution time.

I myself was thinking along the roads of a create index but I'm only new to SQL so any advice or help will be much appreciated !

I'm currently doing 7 sorts. There's a join with another view and therefor the performances are reduced. Is there a way to reduce the number of sorts ? 
When I execute a request from start of 2016 to start of 2017, I get execution times of 40 seconds.
In my Explain, I have nested loops. Is there maybe a way around them ?

What my function does : 
My function collects data from the dates I put in as parameters and associates them with a view and it sends me back a table of which I use on a 3rd party app.

Here's my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION report.get_sa001(
    IN "date_D" timestamp without time zone, 
    IN "date_F" timestamp without time zone, 
    IN frequence integer)
RETURNS TABLE(
    "Period_date" timestamp without time zone, 
    "Site" character varying, 
    "Customer_code" character varying,
    "Internal_reference" character varying, 
    "InvoiceNumber" character varying, 
    "Value_in_currency" numeric, 
    "Value_in_EUR" numeric, 
    "Value_Budget_in_EUR" numeric, 
    "Selling_price_CUR" numeric, 
    "Selling_price_EUR" numeric, 
    "Currency_code" character varying, 
    "Selling_quantity" numeric, 
    "Variance_price_CUR" numeric, 
    "Variance_price_EUR" numeric, 
    "Variance_value_CUR" numeric, 
    "Variance_value_EUR" numeric, 
    "Selling_date" timestamp without time zone) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE p_debut timestamp without time zone;
DECLARE p_fin timestamp without time zone;

BEGIN

p_debut = dw.get_period_end("date_D", "frequence");
p_fin = dw.get_period_end("date_F", "frequence");



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "dates_1" CASCADE;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "dates_1" AS
SELECT p_debut::date + n AS "date", 
       dw.period_frequency(p_debut::date + n) AS "frequency" 
FROM generate_series(0, p_fin::date - p_debut::date) AS x(n)
WHERE (dw.period_frequency(p_debut::date + n) & frequence != 0);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "dates" CASCADE;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "dates" AS
SELECT "date", 
       LAG("date") OVER (ORDER BY "date") AS "date_prev", 
       "frequency" 
FROM "dates_1";

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Sales_over_period" CASCADE;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "Sales_over_period" AS
SELECT "dates"."date"::timestamp without time zone, 
       "FI-D7_Sales".* 
FROM "dates" 
LEFT JOIN dw."FI-D7_Sales"
ON "FI-D7_Sales"."Selling_date" >= COALESCE("dates"."date_prev", "date_D")
AND "FI-D7_Sales"."Selling_date" <= "dates"."date" 
WHERE "FI-D7_Sales"."Selling_date" <= "date_F"
ORDER BY "FI-D7_Sales"."Site", 
         dates."date";

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Ref_price" CASCADE;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "Ref_price" AS        
SELECT "FI-D7_Sales"."Internal_reference",
       SUM ("FI-D7_Sales"."Value_in_currency") As "Ref_value",
       SUM ("FI-D7_Sales"."Qty") As "Ref_quantity",
       "FI-D7_Sales"."Site" 
FROM dw."FI-D7_Sales"
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (
        "FI-D7_Sales"."Internal_reference", "FI-D7_Sales"."Site") 
    "FI-D7_Sales"."Internal_reference",
    "FI-D7_Sales"."Selling_date" As "Ref_date",
    "FI-D7_Sales"."Site"
    FROM dw."FI-D7_Sales"
    WHERE "FI-D7_Sales"."Selling_date"<= "date_D"
    ORDER BY "FI-D7_Sales"."Internal_reference", 
             "FI-D7_Sales"."Site", 
             "FI-D7_Sales"."Selling_date" DESC) FID7_MaxDate
ON "FI-D7_Sales"."Internal_reference" =FID7_MaxDate."Internal_reference" 
AND "FI-D7_Sales"."Site" =FID7_MaxDate."Site" 
AND "FI-D7_Sales"."Selling_date" =FID7_MaxDate."Ref_date"
GROUP BY "FI-D7_Sales"."Internal_reference", 
         "FI-D7_Sales"."Selling_date", 
         "FI-D7_Sales"."Site";

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Sales_with_currency" CASCADE;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "Sales_with_currency" AS              
SELECT "Sales_over_period".*,
    Case 
       WHEN "Ref_price"."Ref_quantity" is Null Then -1
       WHEN "Ref_price"."Ref_quantity" <> 0 Then "Ref_price"."Ref_value"/"Ref_price"."Ref_quantity" 
    ELSE 0
    END AS "Ref_price",
       "C00_Sites"."Accounting_currency", 
       date_trunc('MONTH'::text, "Sales_over_period"."Selling_date") + '1 mon -1 days'::interval AS "eom_date",
       date_trunc('YEAR'::text, "Sales_over_period"."Selling_date") + '1 year -1 days'::interval AS "eoy_date"
FROM "Sales_over_period" 
JOIN dw."C00_Sites" 
ON "Sales_over_period"."Site"::text = "C00_Sites"."Site"::text
LEFT JOIN "Ref_price" 
ON "Sales_over_period"."Site"::text = "Ref_price"."Site"::text 
AND "Sales_over_period"."Internal_reference"::text = "Ref_price"."Internal_reference"::text;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Sales_with_exchangerate" CASCADE;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "Sales_with_exchangerate" AS 
SELECT "Sales_with_currency".*,
       COALESCE(exE."ratePerEur", exE_last."ratePerEur_Last")::numeric(15,4) AS "ratePerEur_E",
       COALESCE(exB."ratePerEur", exB_last."ratePerEur_Last")::numeric(15,4) AS "ratePerEur_B"
FROM "Sales_with_currency"
LEFT JOIN dw."FI-D0_ExchangeRates" AS exE
ON exE."rateType" ='E'
AND "Sales_with_currency"."Accounting_currency" = exE."rateCurrency" 
AND "Sales_with_currency"."eom_date" = exE."rateDate"
LEFT JOIN dw."FI-D0_ExchangeRates_LAST" AS exE_last
ON "Sales_with_currency"."Accounting_currency" = exE_last.rate_cur 
AND exE_last."rate_type" = 'E'
LEFT JOIN dw."FI-D0_ExchangeRates" AS exB
ON exB."rateType" = 'B'
AND "Sales_with_currency"."Accounting_currency" = exB."rateCurrency" 
AND "Sales_with_currency"."eoy_date" = exB."rateDate"
LEFT JOIN dw."FI-D0_ExchangeRates_LAST" AS exB_last
ON "Sales_with_currency"."Accounting_currency" = exB_last.rate_cur 
AND exB_last."rate_type" = 'B';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Sales_final" CASCADE;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "Sales_final" AS 
SELECT "Sales_with_exchangerate"."date",
       "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Site",
       "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Customer_code",
       "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Internal_reference",
       "Sales_with_exchangerate"."InvoiceNumber",
       "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Value_in_currency",
    CASE 
       WHEN "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Accounting_currency" = 'EUR'::bpchar 
       THEN "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Value_in_currency"::numeric(15,4)
    ELSE ("Sales_with_exchangerate"."Value_in_currency" / "Sales_with_exchangerate"."ratePerEur_E")::numeric(15,4)
    END AS "Value_in_EUR",
    CASE 
       WHEN "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Accounting_currency" = 'EUR'::bpchar 
       THEN "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Value_in_currency"::numeric(15,4)
    ELSE ("Sales_with_exchangerate"."Value_in_currency" / "Sales_with_exchangerate"."ratePerEur_B")::numeric(15,4)
    END AS "Value_Budget_in_EUR",
    CASE 
       WHEN "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Qty" = 0 Then 0::numeric(15,4)
    ELSE ("Sales_with_exchangerate"."Value_in_currency"/"Sales_with_exchangerate"."Qty")::numeric(15,4) 
    END AS "Selling_price_CUR",
    CASE 
       WHEN "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Qty" = 0 Then 0::numeric(15,4)
       WHEN "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Accounting_currency" = 'EUR'::bpchar 
       THEN ("Sales_with_exchangerate"."Value_in_currency"/"Sales_with_exchangerate"."Qty")::numeric(15,4)
    ELSE (("Sales_with_exchangerate"."Value_in_currency" / "Sales_with_exchangerate"."ratePerEur_E")/"Sales_with_exchangerate"."Qty")::numeric(15,4)
    END AS "Selling_price_EUR",
       "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Currency_code",
       "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Qty"::numeric(15,4) AS "Selling_quantity",
    CASE 
       WHEN "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Ref_price"=-1 Then -1::numeric(15,4)
    ELSE "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Ref_price"::numeric(15,4) 
    END AS "Variance_price_CUR",
    CASE 
       WHEN "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Ref_price"=-1 Then -1::numeric(15,4)
       WHEN "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Accounting_currency" = 'EUR'::bpchar 
       THEN "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Ref_price"::numeric(15,4)
    ELSE ("Sales_with_exchangerate"."Ref_price" / "Sales_with_exchangerate"."ratePerEur_E")::numeric(15,4)
    END AS "Variance_price_EUR",
    CASE 
       WHEN "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Ref_price"=-1 Then 0::numeric(15,4)
    ELSE ("Sales_with_exchangerate"."Ref_price"*"Sales_with_exchangerate"."Qty")::numeric(15,4)
    END AS "Variance_value_CUR",
    CASE 
       WHEN "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Ref_price" = -1 Then 0::numeric(15,4)
       WHEN "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Accounting_currency" = 'EUR'::bpchar 
       THEN ("Sales_with_exchangerate"."Ref_price"*"Sales_with_exchangerate"."Qty")::numeric(15,4)
    ELSE (("Sales_with_exchangerate"."Ref_price" / "Sales_with_exchangerate"."ratePerEur_E")*"Sales_with_exchangerate"."Qty")::numeric(15,4)
    END AS "Variance_value_EUR",
       "Sales_with_exchangerate"."Selling_date"  
FROM "Sales_with_exchangerate";

RETURN QUERY 

SELECT * 
FROM "Sales_final";

END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

Here's my query and Explain Analyze :

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT d."Selling_date", a."Selling_currency", d."Value_in_EUR", d."Value_in_currency", d."Site"
FROM report.get_sa001('2016-01-01'::date, '2017-03-31'::date, 32) AS d LEFT JOIN report."Axis_RefCustomer" 
AS a ON d."Site" = a."Site" AND d."Internal_reference" = a."Reference_internal" AND d."Customer_code" = a."Customer_code"

Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1.23..2375.17 rows=1000 width=108) (actual time=2471.699..40647.542 rows=53442 loops=1)
  ->  Function Scan on get_sa001 d  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=168) (actual time=2470.512..2485.426 rows=53442 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.98..2.35 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.524..0.714 rows=1 loops=53442)
        Join Filter: (((d."Site")::text = ("T01_References"."Site")::text) AND ((d."Internal_reference")::text = ("T01_References"."Internal_reference")::text) AND (("T02_Customers"."Site")::text = ("T01_References"."Site")::text))
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 126
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..1.42 rows=1 width=33) (actual time=0.011..0.053 rows=127 loops=53442)
              ->  Index Scan using "T02_Customers_pkey" on "T02_Customers"  (cost=0.28..0.77 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=1 loops=53442)
                    Index Cond: ((d."Customer_code")::text = ("Customer_code")::text)
              ->  Index Scan using "T12_RefCustomer_pkey" on "T12_RefCustomer"  (cost=0.29..0.64 rows=1 width=29) (actual time=0.007..0.025 rows=99 loops=68922)
                    Index Cond: ((("Customer_code")::text = ("T02_Customers"."Customer_code")::text) AND (("Site")::text = ("T02_Customers"."Site")::text))
        ->  Index Scan using "T01_References_pkey" on "T01_References"  (cost=0.42..0.92 rows=1 width=22) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=6795175)
              Index Cond: ((("Internal_reference")::text = ("T12_RefCustomer"."Internal_reference")::text) AND (("Site")::text = ("T12_RefCustomer"."Site")::text))
Total runtime: 40650.764 ms
```

What I have done:

I tried turning off the nested loops `SET enable_nestloop = off;`. 
Therefore Postgres decided to use a Hash left join which reduced my total run time down from 40 seconds down to 2.8 seconds. Is Hash a viable solution ?
Is there anything complementary to Hash or to replace it which would reduce even more my execution time ?

Here's my Explain Analyze after I turned the nestloop to off :

```
SET enable_nestloop = off;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT d."Selling_date", a."Selling_currency", d."Value_in_EUR", d."Value_in_currency", d."Site"
FROM report.get_sa001('2016-01-01'::date, '2017-03-31'::date, 32) AS d LEFT JOIN report."Axis_RefCustomer" 
AS a ON d."Site" = a."Site" AND d."Internal_reference" = a."Reference_internal" AND d."Customer_code" = a."Customer_code"


Hash Left Join  (cost=6342.36..6382.37 rows=1000 width=108) (actual time=2774.785..2806.634 rows=53446 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (((d."Site")::text = ("T01_References"."Site")::text) AND ((d."Internal_reference")::text = ("T01_References"."Internal_reference")::text) AND ((d."Customer_code")::text = ("T02_Customers"."Customer_code")::text))
  ->  Function Scan on get_sa001 d  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=168) (actual time=2597.277..2605.074 rows=53446 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=6329.04..6329.04 rows=747 width=28) (actual time=177.496..177.496 rows=13182 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 768kB
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=5275.62..6329.04 rows=747 width=28) (actual time=138.692..174.757 rows=13182 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: ((("T02_Customers"."Site")::text = ("T01_References"."Site")::text) AND (("T12_RefCustomer"."Internal_reference")::text = ("T01_References"."Internal_reference")::text))
              ->  Merge Join  (cost=1747.80..1925.62 rows=3703 width=33) (actual time=111.117..129.543 rows=13182 loops=1)
                    Merge Cond: ((("T12_RefCustomer"."Site")::text = ("T02_Customers"."Site")::text) AND (("T12_RefCustomer"."Customer_code")::text = ("T02_Customers"."Customer_code")::text))
                    ->  Sort  (cost=1250.80..1283.75 rows=13181 width=29) (actual time=84.036..87.813 rows=13182 loops=1)
                          Sort Key: "T12_RefCustomer"."Site", "T12_RefCustomer"."Customer_code"
                          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 528kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on "T12_RefCustomer"  (cost=0.00..348.81 rows=13181 width=29) (actual time=0.004..1.998 rows=13182 loops=1)
                    ->  Sort  (cost=497.00..510.98 rows=5592 width=17) (actual time=27.076..27.486 rows=17525 loops=1)
                          Sort Key: "T02_Customers"."Site", "T02_Customers"."Customer_code"
                          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 607kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on "T02_Customers"  (cost=0.00..148.92 rows=5592 width=17) (actual time=0.003..0.597 rows=5593 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=1973.13..1973.13 rows=74513 width=22) (actual time=26.911..26.911 rows=74513 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 2048  Batches: 4  Memory Usage: 1019kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on "T01_References"  (cost=0.00..1973.13 rows=74513 width=22) (actual time=0.002..11.099 rows=74513 loops=1)
Total runtime: 2810.434 ms
```

Comment: Please present a minimum example, so we don't have to debug tons of irrelevant code before we can get to the core of the question.

Comment: Let's say I want my function to send me back a table for January 2016 to March 2017. The execution time was around 40 seconds to send me back the information I wanted. Once I turned off my nested loop the execution time went down to 5 seconds because Postgre was forced to find another solution and used a Hash join. What I would like to know is can I change anything in my code to reduce that time furthermore ? Maybe a way around using 7 temporary tables which could make the request more efficient ? If you have any other questions I'll be happy to answer them. I hope this helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manually disabling planner methods to force different query plans is a desperate measure of last resort and typically hiding problems, plus causing more problems later. In short: don't.

The solution to your problem is a complete rewrite of the function.

Your temp tables do not have any indexes or even table statistics. You would have to run `ANALYZE` on each temp table manually after creation.

- [Are regular VACUUM ANALYZE still recommended under 9.1?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18664/are-regular-vacuum-analyze-still-recommended-under-9-1/18694#18694)

And possibly create indexes. This would most probably allow (much) better query plans, but add more overhead, yet. Still just putting lipstick on a pig.

**Instead**, replace your complete function body with a **single query** using CTEs or subqueries instead of temp tables. Much less overhead, and indexes and table statistics of the underlying tables can be used. That will be ***much*** faster.

I am not going to do the rewrite for you. Too much work, and well beyond the scope of OT questions here.