# How to get index scan for OR'ed time-range predicates?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, index, postgresql-performance, range-types

I have table `events` with fields:

```
id
user_id
time_start
time_end
...
```

And have b-tree index on `(time_start, time_end)`.

```
SELECT user_id
FROM events
WHERE ((time_start <= '2021-08-24T15:30:00+00:00' AND time_end >= '2021-08-24T15:30:00+00:00') OR
       (time_start <= '2021-08-24T15:59:00+00:00' AND time_end >= '2021-08-24T15:59:00+00:00'))
GROUP BY user_id);
```

```
Group  (cost=243735.42..243998.32 rows=1103 width=4) (actual time=186.533..188.244 rows=166 loops=1)
  Group Key: user_id
  Buffers: shared hit=224848
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=243735.42..243992.80 rows=2206 width=4) (actual time=186.532..188.199 rows=176 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=224848
        ->  Sort  (cost=242735.39..242738.15 rows=1103 width=4) (actual time=184.121..184.126 rows=59 loops=3)
              Sort Key: user_id
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
              Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
              Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 28kB
              Buffers: shared hit=224848
              ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=242668.62..242679.65 rows=1103 width=4) (actual time=184.065..184.085 rows=59 loops=3)
                    Group Key: user_id
                    Buffers: shared hit=224834
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events  (cost=0.00..242553.74 rows=45952 width=4) (actual time=104.085..183.994 rows=64 loops=3)
                          Filter: (((time_start <= '2021-08-24 15:30:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (time_end >= '2021-08-24 15:30:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)) OR ((time_start <= '2021-08-24 15:59:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (time_end >= '2021-08-24 15:59:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 708728
                          Buffers: shared hit=224834
Planning Time: 0.169 ms
Execution Time: 188.294 ms
```

Postgres uses `Seq Scan` with filter:

```
Filter: (((time_start <= '2021-08-24 15:30:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (time_end >= '2021-08-24 15:30:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)) OR ((time_start <= '2021-08-24 15:59:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (time_end >= '2021-08-24 15:59:00+00'::timestamp with time zone)))
```

But when I leave one condition for `time_start` and `time_end` it starts to use Index Scan.

How can I change condition to make Postgres use Index Scan over Seq Scan?

I don't want to use `UNION` like:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM events
WHERE (
     (time_start <= '2021-08-24T15:59:00+00:00' AND time_end >= '2021-08-24T15:59:00+00:00'))
GROUP BY user_id)
UNION (SELECT user_id
       FROM events
       WHERE (
           (time_start <= '2021-08-24T15:59:00+00:00' AND time_end >= '2021-08-24T15:59:00+00:00'))
   GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the *complete* execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)` - not just a "simple" explain.

Comment: Please start any performance question by disclosing your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Expression index

A [GiST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gist.html) or (even better) [**SP-GiST**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/spgist.html) expression **index** on an inclusive timestamp range should work wonders.

```
CREATE INDEX events_right_idx ON events USING spgist (tsrange(time_start, time_end, '[]'));
```

Rewrite your **query** with the ["range contains" operator `@>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE) and match the indexed expression (exactly equivalent to your original):

```
SELECT user_id
FROM   events
WHERE  tsrange(time_start, time_end, '[]') @> timestamp '2021-08-24 15:30:00'
    OR tsrange(time_start, time_end, '[]') @> timestamp '2021-08-24 15:59:00'
GROUP  BY user_id;
```

You'll get a query plan like this:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=9.90..10.00 rows=10 width=4)
  Group Key: user_id
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on events  (cost=2.57..9.88 rows=10 width=4)
        Recheck Cond: ((tsrange(time_start, time_end, ''[]''::text) @> ''2021-08-24 15:30:00''::timestamp without time zone) OR (tsrange(time_start, time_end, ''[]''::text) @> ''2021-08-24 15:59:00''::timestamp without time zone))
        ->  BitmapOr  (cost=2.57..2.57 rows=10 width=0)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on events_right_expr_idx  (cost=0.00..1.28 rows=5 width=0)
                    Index Cond: (tsrange(time_start, time_end, ''[]''::text) @> ''2021-08-24 15:30:00''::timestamp without time zone)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on events_right_expr_idx  (cost=0.00..1.28 rows=5 width=0)
                    Index Cond: (tsrange(time_start, time_end, ''[]''::text) @> ''2021-08-24 15:59:00''::timestamp without time zone)
```

Should be ***much faster***.

Range types assume inclusive lower and exclusive upper bound unless instructed otherwise. `tsrange(time_start, time_end)` is the same as `tsrange(time_start, time_end), '[)'`).
Since you operate with `>=` and `<=`, ***include*** both bounds with `tsrange(time_start, time_end, '[]')`.

Related:

- [Perform this hours of operation query in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22111524/939860)
- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns/39599#39599)

#### Alternatively, store range column in table

Should be a bit faster, yet, as plain (not expression) index.
You can add a timestamp range column to your table, like:

```
ALTER TABLE event ADD COLUMN ts_range tsrange GENERATED ALWAYE AS (tsrange(time_start, time_end, '[]')) STORED;
```

See:

- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8250729/939860)

**Or**, more radically, replace `time_start` and `time_end` with the range column. Then index and query are a bit simpler:

```
CREATE INDEX events_right_idx ON events USING spgist (ts_range);

SELECT user_id
FROM   events
WHERE  ts_range @> timestamp '2021-08-24T15:30:00'
    OR ts_range @> timestamp '2021-08-24T15:59:00'
GROUP  BY user_id;
```

But the `tsrange` column occupies more space than two `timestamp` columns. Weigh cost and benefits.

#### Asides

Postgres 14 (currently beta) even allows a covering SP-GiST index. [The release notes:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/release-14.html#id-1.11.6.5.5.3.5)

> Allow SP-GiST to use INCLUDE'd columns (Pavel Borisov)

But I don't think you can get index-only scans for your particular query.

If you have to make do with your B-tree index for some reason, this fixed `UNION` query shouldn't be too bad:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM   events
WHERE  '2021-08-24T15:30:00' BETWEEN time_start AND time_end
UNION
SELECT user_id
FROM   events
WHERE  '2021-08-24T15:59:00' BETWEEN time_start AND time_end
```

Notably, no `GROUP BY`. `UNION` already does all the work.
And simplify with `BETWEEN` (no effect on performance).

Also, you seem to have a wild mix of `timestamp without time zone` and `timestamp with time zone`. And name it "time" to add to the confusion. Typically `timestamptz` is the better choice. See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

Last, but not least, this indicates inaccurate column statistics, leading to a sub-optimal query plan:

```
 ->  Parallel Seq Scan on events  (cost=0.00..242553.74 rows=45952 width=4)
                                  (actual time=104.085..183.994 rows=64 loops=3)
```

Run

```
ANALYZE events;
```

And retry. Your original query *can* use a plain B-tree index. It's just not as efficient as the suggested SP-GiST index.
And then maybe tune your `autovacuum` and statistics settings to avoid bad statistics in the future. See:

- [Aurora PostgreSQL database using a slower query plan than a normal PostgreSQL for an identical query?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/260429/aurora-postgresql-database-using-a-slower-query-plan-than-a-normal-postgresql-fo/260432#260432)
- [Keep PostgreSQL from sometimes choosing a bad query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8229000/939860)

Comment: thank you for your response.
I have an offtopic question how can I find out what indexes on the table are not used by postgresql?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.